# How can I parse quotes in golang template such that it doesn't get converted to ascii values on rendering of template?

Tags: go, go-templates

I have following variable which I want to be rendered in my template:

```
str := "'~qas\\d{1,2}.abc.com' '~qas\\d{1,2}business.abc.com'"
```

In a template like this:

```
const tpl = `
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{ .Hosts }};

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
`
```

When this template is getting rendered its converting single quotes into ascii value

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name &#39;~qas\d{1,2}.abc.com&#39;
&#39;~qas\d{1,2}business.abc.com&#39;;
 
 
 #error_page  404              /404.html;
 
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
```

The expected output is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name '~qas\d{1,2}.abc.com'
'~qas\d{1,2}business.abc.com';
 
 
 #error_page  404              /404.html;
 
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
```

here's sample code for reproducing the issue and testing it out.
https://go.dev/play/p/h9vj-u--BUz

EDIT1: I am using sprint "github.com/Masterminds/sprig" which is incompatible with `text/template` hence I cannot use `text/template` instead of `html/template`

Comment: @Zombo the reason why we are using html is because of sprig. Just checking if sprig will work with text/template also.

Comment: @Zombo Looks like sprig is not compatible with text/template. https://go.dev/play/p/GxT8piRQPBS :(

Comment: Thanks just realised its `tt.New("").Funcs(sprig.TxtFuncMap()).Parse(tpl)`. Once again thanks every one for the quick response.